# Making it clear to user that Value=0 or Error: Unable to fetch value

Tags: errors, graphs

I have the following use case:

The user can select one or multiple of Items A/B/C... and be shown a time series graph of var X against t for that Item(s). There is only 1 graph shown, so when multiple items are selected, the frontend overlays them into a single graph.

Sometimes, the value of X can just be 0 for the entire duration for an Item(s).
OR there could be a technical error where the data can't be fetched.

This can lead to a situation where the user sees 0 for the entire duration for Item A, they might think its a technical error, when its really the case that the value is 0.

**How do I make this differentiation (Error fetching data VS value=0) clear to the user?**
Especially when Item A might be a case of value=0, Item B is an error, and both are shown on the same graph.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution is to not rely on the graph to indicate an error. Instead, if there is an error fetching data, then inform the user of that with a simple error message somewhere near the graph:

> There was an error fetching the data.

If it is a case that some data points will error, but some will be valid, then change the message like so:

> This graph is only partial representation as some of the data points could not be fetched.

Ideally, if your graphing tools support it, you could colour the erroneous nodes a different colour and let them have a tool tip that states the data could not be fetched.